# Changing x-Axis in r

Tags: r

I would like to change x-axis of a plot in r. For example:

```
r<-c(1:10)
plot(r)
axis(1,at=10/(1:10),labels=NULL)
```

but I see the old values on the x-axis too. I want to have only new values on x-axis.What should I do to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `axes` argument in `plot` function and `frame.plot` argument if you want your plot to have a border, for example:

```
r<-c(1:10)
plot(r, axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
axis(1, at=10/(1:10), labels=NULL)
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), axTicks(2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have this expectation, that I see on the x-axis 10,..,2,....1 but I see values like this 1,...5,....10  how can I solve this problem?

Comment: pass `xlim=c(10,1)` to the `plot()` function. Additionally, `axis(1, at=c(1,2,5,10), labels=NULL)` may be more aesthetic

Comment: @gagolewsthanks but it changes the oriantation of my plot. I would like to change only x-axis

Comment: Running @cena's code you get 1,...,10 on the x-axis. Isn't it what you desire?

Comment: No, It should be:`10,...,1` becuase I want `10/c(1:10)`

Comment: I don't know the function are you trying to plot. But it seems that you want to change the values of the `labels` arg in `axis` :)

Comment: Maybe you should try `labels=rev(10/(1:10))`. Is this what you want?